# How to use Sankey chart from highchart in Angular5

Tags: highcharts, angular5, sankey-diagram, highcharts-ng

I have been using angular5 and have install the highchart using npm install.

Now I am able to use all the chart using the same except the sankey charts.

It gives me hightchart error 17.

Please help.

Comment: Did you read the [error description](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/17) ? Please read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit our question.

Comment: Yes its says error 17, but rest of the charts are working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app.module.ts file add these three lines it will will work.

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as highchartsSankey from 'highcharts/modules/sankey';
highchartsSankey(Highcharts);
```

Comment: Is `sankey` chart available in Highcharts version `5.0.14`?

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/ @ArpitMeena check this link.

Answer (score 0):

Sankey chart type is a separate module, so you have to import it:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
require('highcharts/modules/sankey')(Highcharts);
```

Comment: Is `sankey` chart available in Highcharts version `5.0.14`?
I am not able to find this module inside `node_modules/highcharts/modules/` folder.

Comment: Hi @Arpit Meena, The `sankey` chart type is available since Highcharts 6.